# How can I add annotations to a plot that uses facet_grid with plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a chart in plotly and I'm having trouble getting annotations to work.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/get-the-best-from-ggplotly/) and have my code set up like this.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(plotly)

gg <- bb %>% 
  ggplot(aes(week, value, color = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x)(ifelse(x > 1000000, paste0("$", x / 1000000, "M"), 
                                                 ifelse(x < 1000000, paste0("$", x / 1000000, "M"),
                                                        ifelse(x > 1000, paste0("$", x / 1000, "K"), x))))) +
  facet_grid(type~., scales="free") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") 

mytext2 <- paste("Type = ", bb$type, "\n", "Week = ", bb$week, "\n", "Value = ", dollar(as.numeric(bb$value)), "\n", sep = "")
plotly_build(gg)   %>% 
  style(text=mytext2, hoverinfo = "text", traces = c(1, 2, 3)) %>% 
  layout(title = "A look at the Customer Journey Starting with Their First Week",
         font = list(size = 12),
         xaxis = list(title = "Weeks from Account Creation"),
         font = list(size = 9),
         yaxis = list(title = "Balance"),
         font = list(size = 9)
  )
```

This is my data.

```
# A tibble: 180 x 3
    week type      value
   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
 1     0 Median   -32.0 
 2     1 Median   -47.9 
 3     2 Median    -0.01
 4     3 Median     2.62
 5     4 Median    94.8 
 6     5 Median   192.  
 7     6 Median  1352.  
 8     7 Median  2665.  
 9     8 Median  4085.  
10     9 Median  4306.  
# … with 170 more rows
```

You can see in the visualization here that every label is `Type = Median` instead of the proper type.

> Here is the visualization: https://rpubs.com/sebrpubs/example